# Hide or show links depending on if the user is authenticated - AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently working on an `AngularJS` application, I've hit a road block which is the following.

We've got a `login` page when the user submits we call a web api and authenticate the user, we're currently using claims authentication to set the cookie etc that's working as expected however the issue I have is hiding and showing links depending on if the user is logged in or not.  I've easily been able to resolve this when I've worked in MVC by doing the following inside the `layout.cshtml`:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
  Show additional links to user once they're authenticated
}
else
{
  Show the standard links
}
```

Now as I'm using straight HTML (no `Razor` files) but I am building this within `Visual Studio` I'm stumped on how I go about showing certain links depending if the user is `authenticated` within a `.html` page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-if`:

```
<div ng-if="user.identity.isAuthenticated">
    <a>Important link here</a>
</div>
<div ng-if="!user.identity.isAuthenticated">
    <a>Standard link here</a>
</div>
```

Something like this would work, depending on your requirements. Since this is all client side however, it's not going to be as secure, as on the server side. So be careful with that.

Comment: Hey Luka, thanks for the code snippet.  Could you please elaborate on what you said i.e wont be as secure as on server side?

Comment: @Luka I don't think that it does really matter in terms of security, say the link is a protected route on the app. You can put a resolve in the protected state to verify that the user is already logged in. And if the right system is well made on server side. The user would just see an empty template if he manages to bypass it anyways, nothing risky.

Comment: can give the user a token when they're authenticated then check if token is existed? then if it doesn't then just redirect them somewhere.

Comment: Well all your code is contained on the client, so if you have any secret information you might want to request it dynamically from the server instead of putting it in static html.

Comment: @Sami Triki yup most of the time it's not a problem, but if you put a secret link in the template it can be read from the client.

Comment: I won't be storing anything secret on the client, I will be protecting the given routes that require Authentication, so if by chance an individual is able to guess a particular URL then within the given route I'll redirect them if they're not logged in.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. I know the angular is working because if I remove the ng-app in the body tag, it stays visible. But with it, my div is always removed, even when the user has logged in. I know that User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is returning try because I'm using it elsewhere on the page and if it were false I wouldn't see part of the page.