# angular ng-if not working

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ng-if

Here's my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/dropdownhover")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body ng-app>
    <div class="navbar-fixed-top">
        @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            @Html.Action("_Index", "MainMenu")
        }
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <footer class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
            <div ng-if="User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" style="margin:10px;">
                Hello, @ViewBag.User
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/dropdownhover")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootbox")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

For some reason, it would seem that "User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" is either false or undefined as far as angular is concerned, as my "Hello, @ViewBag.User" is never visible.  But the "User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" above that, which shows my main menu, works fine.

I assume I'm missing something silly, but I can't seem to figure out what, as I'm doing it the same as another article on here instructed.

Comment: "ng-app" should be ng-app="yourAppName"...

Answer (score 0):

add @ before the 2nd User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

Correction: should be '@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated' === 'True'

However, Razor doesn't like ng-** so they should be used as data-ng-**, to prevent razor from parsing those

Comment: I already tried that. If I do that, it then shows me the div when it shouldn't and not when it should. Meaning I have to put a "not" (!) in front. That gives me the desired result, but clearly it's not working correctly.

Comment: '@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated' === 'true' 
razor will produce 'true' === 'true'  if logged-in
else razor will produce 'false' === 'true'  
both of these will satisfy the ng-if

Comment: No, that doesn't work at all. Makes it hidden all the time.

I'm trying to do what is described here (and marked as the answer), but it doesn't work for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36383981/hide-or-show-links-depending-on-if-the-user-is-authenticated-angularjs

Comment: That page is not using Razor anymore. Are you removing Razor and creating straight html pages? I'm assuming not. In that case, since you're using razor, why bother using ng-if at all? If you're converting razor into html you need to ensure "User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" has true/false value through javascript. As you can see in that example the answer refers to "user.identity.isAuthenticated", which is assumed to be javascript variable.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm a beginner with both Razor and Angular. I'm not sure what you mean by "page is not using Razor anymore". The Razor syntax above works just fine. I realize I could do the same thing down below instead of using Angular, but I'm trying things out and this seemed like a simple task to see it in action.

So based on your variable idea (assuming I understood it), I changed the body tag to be:

    <body ng-app ng-init="auth=@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated">

and the ng-if to:

    <div ng-if="auth" style="margin:10px;">

But that still doesn't work.

Comment: I also tried:

              <div ng-if="@(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)" style="margin:10px;">

but that does the opposite of what I expect, as mentioned in an earlier comment.

Comment: Using ng-if with variable that isn't going to change, is same as hard coding. 
with razor you would do exactly as the person did asking the question in comment you linked.  You have the right idea but you're using it wrong. As you can see there is nothing that's going to change auth from true to false so you will never see it change unelss you refreshed the page. Which means you can just use Razor instead. sorry changing link...
https://plnkr.co/edit/HJA8UWnHx6J522VDicaD?p=preview

Comment: But shouldn't @(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) evaluate based on whether I've logged in or not? It does it correctly for the section at the top. So why isn't Angular evaluating that expression correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161551/discussion-between-axr-and-starfleet-security).